# How to avoid integer overflow of fixed point in rasterization

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, direct3d, rasterizing

Direct3d 11 uses fixed point in rasterization.

> The Rasterizer(15) must support 16.8 (integer.fraction) fixed point precision for x and y.
> (Direct3D 11.3 Functional Specifications).

By using 16.8 bits as fixed point precision, x, y range of viewport is [-32768(-2^15), 32767(=2^15-1)] in direct3d 11.

Then, I have question of above specifications.
 Rasterization uses edge function, that is as follow, to test pixels are inside the triangle and calculate degree of interpolation(= barycentric coordinates).

> Edge function of line contains vertex 0, 1:
> (p.x - v0.x) * (v1.y - v0.y) - (p.y - v0.y) * (v1.x - v0.x)
> (p is pixel position, vn is vertex n position, assume cw)

Edge function has multiplication of component of coordinate. If range of components of coordinates are [-32768, 32767], it required 32.16 fixed point to avoid overflow.
** How to avoid overflow of fixed point by using 16.8 fixed point in rasterization with viewport range is [-32768, 32767]?**

---

I tried several methods to solve this problem. But can't solve it.
Several methods are as follow:

1. Advance with adding difference of edge function
    I calculate each difference of edge function as difference of x, y. and increase with edge function value of initial pixel to process rasterization. But edge function value of initial pixel is 32.16 fixed point. It hasn't difference with using 32.16 fixed point.
     This try is thinking of mentioned method in below link. Because of lack of my English skill, I fail to understand it.
   Could somebody explain it more detail?

> https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/triangle-rasterization-in-practice/
> Last paragraph of Sub-pixel precision

2. Advance with adding difference of edge function / (2 * triangle size)
    Range of barycentric coordinates in triangle is [0, 1]. I use it, that is value of division of edge function by (2 * triangle size) is barycentric coordinates, to test position of triangle and interpolate without overflow in triangle.
    But overflow is occurred in outside pixel of triangle. To rasterize, I calculate min, max coordinates of triangle and rasterize pixel in an *axis aligned bounding box* consists of them. If the size of the triangle is enough small, overflow can be occurred in outside pixel of triangle. So it also doesn't solution.
    If I uses scanline rasterization with Bresenham line algorithm, can choice inner pixel of triangle. and overflow isn't occurred. But I don't try this because I think Direct3d 11 uses brute force method that is testing all pixels in an aabb covers triangle for efficient using of a GPU.

Comment: The rasterizer has to support 16.8 inputs, but that doesn't mean that it has to use 16.8 for all internal calculations.  You can convert to 32.16 or anything else whenever you want.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  Then why did direct3d 11 mention that it uses 16.8 fixed point?
I know direct3d 11 doesn't offer user manipulates data type related with rasterization. So I thought 16.8 fixed point is used in all process of it. 
// And comparing with bigger memory fixed point or floating point, I thought it is efficient at memory bandwidth from cpu to gpu and speed. If direct3d 11 converts 16.8 fixed point to bigger memory fixed point in gpu, it has loss of speed. Despite this, is 16.8 fixed point used in rasterization because of the process faster than floating point and small bandwidth?

Comment: The spec details *requirements* for the rasterizer.  It's going to get 16.8 coordinates for x and y, so it is *required* to support that.  The spec allows implementors to produce rasterizers that are *compatible* with Direct3d.  The spec does not detail *how* a rasterizer works.  Anyone who implements a rasterizer can do it however they want as long as it meets the requirements.